# Possible hardware/internet problem - Selenium bot stops working

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I've designed a selenium bot that navigates through pages downloading content. However, after navigating through around a thousand pages, once it starts downloading content, after 40 or so iterations, the browser has already become very slow, and so, sometimes, my time.sleep(2) checks are not enough for the page to load, and I get errors which crash the program.

That being said, I'd like to know what solutions could I implement. Clearing Firefox cache? Optimizing some sort of configuration?

Edit: I already have a WebDriverWait check, which waits until the element I want to click on is located. Even with this, it says the element is stale. Maybe I should check if the element is clickable?

Comment: what sort of errors do you get? Could you use exceptions or try ... statements to try to catch the exceptions and e.g. trigger another sleep() command?

Comment: StaleElementReferenceException. Something about how the page has been refreshed/the element is no longer attached to DOM. But the thing is - it is, it is a link that is always there, consistently. I put all sorts of timers, and still it crashes after many iterations.